# Dois builds diferentes mesmo fonte Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debug, release

Tenho uma *solution* com vários projetos. Preciso criar dois "perfis" de *builds* diferentes para duas situações. Isto é possível?

No build A eu vou mostrar os menus X, Y e Z.
No build B eu vou mostrar apenas os menus Y e Z.

Tem como eu colocar alguma configuração no meu código e configurar o *build* para gerar essas duas versão a minha escolha?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa criar uma nova configuração no VS. Peguei algumas imagens para ajudar na [página do Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx).

Vá ao `Configuration Manager`:

[image: Configuration Manager]

Crie uma nova configuração no seletor onde provavelmente já tem `Debug` e `Release`. e escolha uma delas com fonte de cópia. Você poderá criar uma versão nova sua para *debug* e uma outra para *release*:

[image: Nova configuração]

Depois você irá na página de propriedades do seu projeto. Na *tab* `Build` você vai criar um **símbolo de compilação condicional**. Seria bom usar um nome igual ao nome que usou na nova configuração criada, só para padronizar. Obviamente criará este símbolo escolhendo o nova configuração que criou.

[image: Build tab]

Aí no seu código você usará `#if SIMBOLO_CRIADO` para escolher se aquele trecho de código deve ser compilado naquela versão ou não.

```
#if MENU1
    ChamaMenu1();
#elif MENU2
    ChamaMenu2();
#endif
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/IfDiretive.cs).

[Documentação da diretiva de compilação condicional](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Cuidado com isto, se abusar você começa se perder.

[Documentação do gerenciador de configurações](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-edit-configurations?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Exatamente isso!